# Paid membership Pro Rest API

Tags: rest-api, membership

Hello I'm trying to retrieve membership levels for any given user from a desktop application , after I did some research I have found this code :

```
/*
Call to http://yoursite.com/?verify=email@domain.com&secret=CHECK to 
check the membership level of a user.
*/
function my_init_pmpro_mini_api()
{
if(function_exists('pmpro_getMembershipLevelForUser') && 
    !empty($_REQUEST['verify']) && 
    !empty($_REQUEST['secret']))
{
    if($_REQUEST['secret'] != "CHECK")
        wp_die("Invalid secret.");

    $user = get_user_by("email", str_replace(" ", "+", 
($_REQUEST['verify'])));
    if(empty($user))
        wp_die("User not found.");

    $membership_level = pmpro_getMembershipLevelForUser();
    if(empty($membership_level))
        die("0");

    //user and membership level found, output json encoded membership level 
       info
    echo json_encode($membership_level);        

    exit;
}
 }
 add_action('init', 'my_init_pmpro_mini_api');
```

My question is : in witch file should I add this snippet in order for my website to start responding to those requests?

Comment: without knowing more about the plugin you're referring to, and judging simply by the line `add_action('init', 'my_init_pmpro_mini_api');` I'd say either the _functions.php_ of your theme, or perhaps from your own plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you will need to have the plugin installed (paidmembershipspro ) otherwise you wont be able to call the function "pmpro_getMembershipLevelForUser" and then you just need to copy the code below to your functions.php file which is inside your WordPress theme.

```
/*
Call to http://yoursite.com/?verify=email@domain.com&secret=CHECK to 
check the membership level of a user.
*/
function my_init_pmpro_mini_api()
{
if(function_exists('pmpro_getMembershipLevelForUser') && 
!empty($_REQUEST['verify']) && 
!empty($_REQUEST['secret']))
{
if($_REQUEST['secret'] != "CHECK")
    wp_die("Invalid secret.");

$user = get_user_by("email", str_replace(" ", "+",
($_REQUEST['verify'])));
if(empty($user))
    wp_die("User not found.");

$membership_level = pmpro_getMembershipLevelForUser();
if(empty($membership_level))
    die("0");

//user and membership level found, output json encoded membership level 
   info
echo json_encode($membership_level);        

exit;
}
}
add_action('init', 'my_init_pmpro_mini_api');
```

Comment: didn't work when adding to theme and
the plugin doesn't have a function.php file ,

Comment: Got it to wok thank's , the cashing plugin was the problem